# how to combine these two python scripts?

Tags: python, python-3.x

how to combine these two python scripts. I am trying to use it in eventghost to capture screenshot of active windows with title name

i can use the screenshots to restore a pc session incase windows crash

sorry , if i formatted my question in bad format. i came back here after a long time and tried my best to put my query in best way

```
import ImageGrab, datetime
im = ImageGrab.grab()
date = datetime.datetime.now()
str = date.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
im.save(r'D:\temp\DELETE NOW\screenshot%s.png' % str)

---------------------------

import win32gui
w=win32gui
w.GetWindowText (w.GetForegroundWindow())
```

Comment: In what order they should be executed?

Comment: The code snippet you posted *is* already one script. Now I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: @mario_sunny i want to combine them such that in result , the filename or the screenshot name is the title name of the window with date as suffix

Comment: @pratik gandhi such that both combined produce a file with window title name and date as suffix

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what order you want to run them in, but:

```py
import ImageGrab, datetime
import win32gui

w=win32gui
w.GetWindowText (w.GetForegroundWindow())

im = ImageGrab.grab()
date = datetime.datetime.now()
str = date.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
im.save(r'D:\temp\DELETE NOW\screenshot%s.png' % str)
```

Comment: i want to combine them such that in result , the filename or the screenshot name is the title name of the window with date as suffix

Comment: it is saving the screenshots but the naming is not working